# Hide first li of specific class

Tags: html, css

Suppose the following HTML code:

```
<ul class="cart not-empty-cart">
    <li class="cart-item" data-cart-key="0">aaaaa</li>
    <li class="cart_item subtotal">bbbb</li>
    <li class="cart_item delivery_fee">cccc</li>
    <li class="cart_item subtotal">dddd</li>
    <li class="cart_item delivery_fee">eeee</li>
    <li class="cart_item total">fff</li>
    <li class="cart_item checkout">gggg</li>
</ul>
```

As you can notice there are two occurrences of `.cart_item.subtotal` and `.cart_item.delivery_fee`. What I want is to hide the first occurrences of each of them. So I want to hide bbbb and cccc `li`'s.

I tried with

```
li.cart_item.subtotal:nth-of-type(1),
li.cart_item.delivery_fee:nth-of-type(1) {
    display: none;
}
```

which doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The :nth-of-type() CSS pseudo-class matches elements based on their position among siblings of the same type (tag name)

Comment: @DenverCoder1 how can I implicate a class in the "equation" then?

Answer (score 3):

The `:nth-of-type()` CSS pseudo-class matches elements based on their position among siblings of the same type (tag name). See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type).

Since the second `li` is the one you want to hide, this pseudo-class will not help you.

Here is one way to do it that takes two steps:

- Hide all occurrences of the given selector
- Show all occurrences that are preceded by a matching selector as a sibling (the `~` can be used to mark "sibling of" - [see docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator))

```css
/* Hide all li.cart_item.subtotal and li.cart_item.delivery_fee */
li.cart_item.subtotal,
li.cart_item.delivery_fee {
    display: none;
}
/* Show ones that have a previous sibling of the same classes */
li.cart_item.subtotal ~ li.cart_item.subtotal,
li.cart_item.delivery_fee ~ li.cart_item.delivery_fee {
    display: list-item;
}
```

```html
<ul class="cart not-empty-cart">
    <li class="cart_item" data-cart-key="0">aaaaa</li>
    <li class="cart_item subtotal">bbbb</li>
    <li class="cart_item delivery_fee">cccc</li>
    <li class="cart_item subtotal">dddd</li>
    <li class="cart_item delivery_fee">eeee</li>
    <li class="cart_item total">fff</li>
    <li class="cart_item checkout">gggg</li>
</ul>
```

---

A more concise way that another user posted and deleted (not sure who) can involve combining the two steps:

- Select occurrences to hide that do not *also* match the preceding sibling selector

```css
/*
 * Hide all li.cart_item.subtotal and li.cart_item.delivery_fee
 * that are not preceded by a sibling of the same selector.
 */
li.cart_item.subtotal:not(li.cart_item.subtotal ~ *),
li.cart_item.delivery_fee:not(li.cart_item.delivery_fee ~ *) {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="cart not-empty-cart">
    <li class="cart_item" data-cart-key="0">aaaaa</li>
    <li class="cart_item subtotal">bbbb</li>
    <li class="cart_item delivery_fee">cccc</li>
    <li class="cart_item subtotal">dddd</li>
    <li class="cart_item delivery_fee">eeee</li>
    <li class="cart_item total">fff</li>
    <li class="cart_item checkout">gggg</li>
</ul>
```

---

With CSS Level 4 selectors, you can use the :nth-child(x of y) selector, but **it does not have good browser support yet**.

```
/* This will not work in most browsers, may work in Safari */
:nth-child(1 of .cart_item.subtotal) {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the DenverCoder1's solution but i'd like to add that you can also achieve this with the help of [:has pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has), Firefox support is still behind a [flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has#browser_compatibility) so probably it's better not to use this in production yet

```css
.subtotal:has(~ .subtotal){
  display: none
}

.delivery_fee:has(~ .delivery_fee) {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<ul class="cart not-empty-cart">
  <li class="cart-item" data-cart-key="0">aaaaa</li>
  <li class="cart_item subtotal">bbbb</li>
  <li class="cart_item delivery_fee">cccc</li>
  <li class="cart_item subtotal">dddd</li>
  <li class="cart_item delivery_fee">eeee</li>
  <li class="cart_item total">fff</li>
  <li class="cart_item checkout">gggg</li>
</ul>
```